# Asynhronious socket: block this thread before all data are sent

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asynchronous, iasyncresult

Regarding `asynchronious sockets`, I would like to know if its possible to hold the thread, before all the data are sent?

With use of [`Socket.BeginSend`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h44aee9.aspx)

```
public IAsyncResult BeginSend(
byte[] buffer,
int offset,
int size,
SocketFlags socketFlags,
AsyncCallback callback,
Object state
```

I send data inside buffer parameter. I would like to know if is it possible to block the thread some how before all data are really sent from here (without regarding if data are received on the other side)? So I can call a `Socket.BeginReceive` method?

--

Will it be good enough to use a `ManualResetEvent` delegate (I called it "sendDone")?

Example:

```
 private static ManualResetEvent sendDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
 //inisde a method call WaitOne() method:
 sendDone.WaitOne();
```

Is this good enough? Or are there any better alterantives?

thx for the ans

Comment: Why use an async method for a synchronous call?.. It would be easier to just not use the async method.

Comment: synchronous call? Which one is synchronous? The one I use are all asynchronious... at least as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the [`Send` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.send.aspx) on the [`Socket` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/attbb8f5.aspx), as it blocks the calling thread, like so:

```
byte[] buffer = ...;

int bytesSent = socket.Send(bytes);
```

Note that if you really wanted to block on the call to BeginSend, you can use the Task Parallel Library to create a [`Task<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx) which you can then wait on, like so:

```
Task<int> task = Task.Factory.FromAsync(
    socket.BeginSend(buffer, offset, size, socketFlags, null, null), 
    socket.EndSend);

// Wait on the task.
task.Wait();

// Get the result.
// Note, you can omit the call to wait above, the call to 
// Result will block.
int bytesSent = task.Result;
```